# How do I set the map point of a KML placemark?

Tags: kml

I am currently placing custom markers on a Google Map with the geoXML3 tool. I am very happy with how it all works, and the ease of generating the KML on the fly and having the marks show on my map.

Since my markers are custom, the 'origin point' is not necessarily the same for each mark. Is there a way with KML to specify the pixel position that gets used as the origin point when the marker is placed on the map?

For instance, all my custom markers are 32x32 PNGs. But the acual visible imagery is say 8x24, centered in the 32x32 area. I would like for my origin point for this marker to be (16,28), so that the bottom of my visible imagery is placed at the point specified in the KML Placemark attribute.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to define that in KML is with the [hotspot tag](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#hotspot)

```
<hotSpot x="0.5" y="0.5" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction">
    Specifies the position within the Icon that is "anchored" to the <Point> specified in the Placemark. The x and y values can be specified in three different ways: as pixels ("pixels"), as fractions of the icon ("fraction"), or as inset pixels ("insetPixels"), which is an offset in pixels from the upper right corner of the icon. The x and y positions can be specified in different ways—for example, x can be in pixels and y can be a fraction. The origin of the coordinate system is in the lower left corner of the icon.

        x - Either the number of pixels, a fractional component of the icon, or a pixel inset indicating the x component of a point on the icon.
        y - Either the number of pixels, a fractional component of the icon, or a pixel inset indicating the y component of a point on the icon.
        xunits - Units in which the x value is specified. A value of fraction indicates the x value is a fraction of the icon. A value of pixels indicates the x value in pixels. A value of insetPixels indicates the indent from the right edge of the icon.
        yunits - Units in which the y value is specified. A value of fraction indicates the y value is a fraction of the icon. A value of pixels indicates the y value in pixels. A value of insetPixels indicates the indent from the top edge of the icon.
```

Comment: Sweet! Thanks. Not sure how I missed that.

Comment: Ok, guess I spoke too soon. This does not seem to be working. I am applying a hotSpot using the insetPixels option.

Comment: Which branch of geoxml3?  I think the only the [kmz branch](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/source/browse/#svn%2Fbranches%2Fkmz) implements that (and I'm not sure how well tested it is).

Comment: That is very old and unsupported.  If you need hotspot, use the kmz branch, if you find problems with it please open [an issue in the geoxml3 issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/issues/list).